# How to link in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, hyperlink

I want to link each of the six images outputted to a different external link, how do I do this?

```
<? $accreditations = array(
     'One' => 'picone',
     'Two' => 'pictwo', 
     'Three' => 'picthree',
     'Four' => 'picfour',
     'Five' => 'picfive',
     'Six' => 'picsix'); ?>
<ul class="accreditations<?=$accreditations_extra_class?>"><?

foreach($accreditations as $alt => $img){
    ?><li><picture alt="<?=$alt?>" class="responsive-image">
        <source srcset="<?=get_bloginfo('template_url')?>/inc/img/accreditation--<?=$img?>--74.png, <?=get_bloginfo('template_url')?>/inc/img/accreditation--<?=$img?>.png 2x" media="(max-width: 339px)">
        <source srcset="<?=get_bloginfo('template_url')?>/inc/img/accreditation--<?=$img?>--103.png, <?=get_bloginfo('template_url')?>/inc/img/accreditation--<?=$img?>.png 2x" media="(min-width: 340px) and (max-width: 459px)">
        <source srcset="<?=get_bloginfo('template_url')?>/inc/img/accreditation--<?=$img?>.png" media="(min-width:340px)">
        <img srcset="<?=get_bloginfo('template_url')?>/inc/img/accreditation--<?=$img?>--74.png" alt="<?=$alt?>" />
    </picture></li><?
} // SPACING REMOVED TO GUARANTEE NO EXTRA SPACING ADDED BETWEEN ITEMS ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: <a href="page.html">Click here</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change your $accreditations variable so each array value points at a value holding both the image url and link url

```
$accreditations = array('one' => ['link' => 'http://etc.com', 'img' => 'http://image.png'], 'two' => ...
```

Then within your `foreach($accreditations as $alt => $img){` the $img value will be equal to that array holding link and img. So to get the image url out just use $img['img'] and to get the link which you should put into an  tag use something like `a href="<?=$img['link']?>">Click here</a>` which wraps around the image or whatever you want to be linked